# Can we get a "blatantly off-topic" close reason?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Can we get a "blatantly off-topic" primary close reason? Do we have any free slots left and if not, could we replace the driving techniques reason?

If you take a look at [the close stats](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) (requires > 2k rep I think), for the last 90 days we've got:

- 42 too broad
- 37 unclear
- 29 duplicate
- 10 custom reasons stating "not about motor vehicle maintenance & repair" (I counted.)
- 8 price-shopping
- 2 opinion based
- 2 belongs on a different site
- 1 driving techniques

Those 10 "not about MV M&R" reasons could be maybe 12-13 depending on how you count, I just counted ones that very explicitly said that.

This means that blatantly off-topic is actually our 4th most popular close reason, at least in the last 90 days, while driving techniques comes dead last.

So I think this is a good case for adding the off-topic reason. I don't see a problem with leaving the driving techniques reason except if it is taking up the only remaining reason slot - the driving technique thing could easily fall under "blatantly off-topic" or be served by custom reasons.

---

Current stats page at the time of this post:

[image]

Comment: Lol, actually, "voting to close as off-topic because of what Moab said" ties with driving techniques.